# Tabris 0.11 iOS EXC_BAD_ACCESS Geolocation

Tags: ios, geolocation, exc-bad-access, tabris

First of all: Thanks that I got such a good and fast feedback from you guys a few days ago.

I'm still playing around in Tabris 0.11 and tried to implement a Geolocation like you guys did in the demo project.

Everything is working great on Android, but under iOS (IPhone 5) I get the error

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xbbadbeef)
```

Here is how my code looks like

```
public void create( Composite parent, UIContext context ) {
    // creation of the layout types
    createLayouts();
    parent.setLayout( GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().margins( 0, 0 ).spacing( 0, 0 ).create() );
    createContainer( parent );
    createBrowser();     
  }

private void createLayouts() {
    layoutGrid = new GridLayout();
    layoutGrid.numColumns = 1;
    layoutGridData = new GridData();
    layoutGridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
}

 private void createContainer( Composite parent ) {
    [...]
    containerBrowser = new Composite( parent, SWT.NONE );
    containerBrowser.setLayout( layoutGrid );
    containerBrowser.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true ) );
    [...]
  }

  private void createBrowser() {
     browser = new Browser( containerBrowser, SWT.NONE );
     browser.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true ) );
     lastLat = 48.775418;
     lastLon = 9.181759;
     setBrowserUrl( lastLat, lastLon);
  }

  private void setBrowserUrl( double lat, double lon) {
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
     builder.append( "http://open.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v4/getmap" );
     builder.append( "?size=" + 200 + "," + 200 );
     builder.append( "&zoom=16" );
     lastLat = lat;
     lastLon = lon;
     builder.append( "&center=" + lat + "," + lon );
     builder.append( "&imageType=png" );
     if( lastLabel != null ) {
       builder.append( "&pois=" + lastLabel + "," + lat + "," + lon + ",0,0" );
     }
     browser.setUrl( builder.toString() );
  }
```

I'm not really experienced in iOS, I hope this information helps you guys.

Thanks in advance, Toby

Comment: Any updates on the issue?

Answer (score 2):

With the example you've provided, I could not reproduce the problem. Maybe what you are seeing is an issue in the pre-release Tabris 0.11 client. The issue might be already fixed in the final Tabris 1.0 release.

I suggest you download Tabris 1.0 ( http://developer.eclipsesource.com/tabris/downloads/ ) and try again.

If you still have a problem, send my your "Device Log" of the crashed App using the "Xcode Organizer".